# Django models - how to track a field on an object when value of the field depends on the different users?

Tags: django, django-models

I want a `Book` object with the field `is_read`, but the value of the `is_read` depends on the `user`.  When I first created this app I was only thinking of one user (me).

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

But if the app has multiple users then of course the `is_read` needs to change according to the user.

**new models**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class IsRead(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=CASCADE)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I think adding the `IsRead` class will help but I need an `IsRead` object to automatically be created every time a new `user` or `book` is created. Not only that, but every time a new user is created, I have to iterate through all the books. Or if a new book is added, I have to iterate through all the users. This seems like a lot of db work just to keep track of who has read what books.

Even if the above is the correct strategy I don't know how to I would do it. I did try to overwrite `AdminModel` to save the `IsRead` but this did not work. I did not get any errors, but the `IsRead` did not save.

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'author')

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        IsRead.objects.update_or_create(book=id, user=request.user, defaults={'book': self.book, 'user': obj.user, 'my_status': False})
        super(BookAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change
```

Comment: Why do you need `is_read` field? You can simply add many to many relation between Book and User. In this way, you will be able to get all the users who read a particular book. Similarly, you will also be able to retrieve all books read by a specific user.

Comment: I was thinking more of `is_read` is the status of the book being read. A m2m relationship between Book and User would be more like the user owns the book.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed solution of using an `IsRead` class to track progress will be very expensive for your db not to mention there will be a lot of unnecessary rows saved. The creation for these models can be synced, however, using [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/).

You can do it something like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Book)
def on_book_create(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if not created or kwargs.get("raw"):
        return
    
    # fetch all users
    # loop through users and create an IsRead object
```

and do a counterpart signal for `on_create_user` too where you fetch all books and create an `IsRead` object linked to that user.

A better way is to leverage the power of [Many-to-Many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) relationship in django. Start by adding a field for this relationship

```
class Book(models.Model):
    ...
    readers = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

You can then add readers to a book instance like this:

```
# 1, 2, 3 are user pks
book.readers.add(1, 2, 3)
# or a user instance
book.readers.add(user)
```

After that, we can add custom functions to the `User` and `Book` models to give us if a book was read by a user or if a user has read a certain book.

```py
class User(models.Model):
    ...
    def has_read(self, book_id):
        return self.book_set.filter(pk=book_id).exists()


class Book(models.Model):
    ...
    def is_read(self, user_id):
        return self.readers.filter(pk=user_id).exists()
```

To check, we can do it like so:

```
user.has_read(book.pk)

# or like this

book.is_read(user.pk)
```

And as a bonus, you can get the books read by the user `user.book_set.all()` as well as all readers of that book `book.readers.all()`

Lastly, for this:

> I was thinking more of is_read is the status of the book being read. A
> m2m relationship between Book and User would be more like the user
> owns the book.

If you want to represent a user's ownership to a certain book you can add a different many-to-many field like `owners` or something. Just like in real life, your relationship to a book is not limited to your ownership with it.

Adding another many-to-many relationship using the same model requires the `related_name` parameter to be set though. This is to avoid confusing django which relationship you want to get.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    ...
    readers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="read_books")
    owners = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="owned_books")
```

You can have query `book->user` relationship using the field name `book.readers.all()` or `book.owners.all()` but for the reverse, you need to reference the related name for each: `user.read_books.all()` or `user.owned_books.all()`.

This is not really far from your original `IsRead` class as django creates a pivot table for book and user models behind the scenes which looks something like this:

[image: many-to-many-pivot-table]

And instead of having a dedicated `is_read` field to check for the read status, the existence of the record implies it that's why we use `.exists()`

Putting them all together to something like:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def has_read(self, book_id):
        return self.read_books.filter(pk=book_id).exists()

    def owns_book(self, book_id):
        return self.owned_books.filter(pk=book_id).exists()

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    readers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="read_books")
    owners = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="owned_books")

    def is_read(self, user_id):
        return self.readers.filter(pk=user_id).exists()

    def is_owned(self, user.id):
        return self.owners.filter(pk=user.id).exists()
```

Comment: If I already have ` readers = models.ManyToManyField(User)`, can I have another field `owners = models.ManyToManyField(User)`?

Comment: Yes! You actually can. Let me update my answer.